# Tokenize words stored in a string in Python

Tags: python

So in my program, I have an input text file. I iterate through the list, add all the words in the list into a string called "text". Then, I use tokenizer on the string, which fails.

```
x = open("Tokens.txt")
text = ""
for line in iter(x):

   text += line[0:-1] + " "

x.close()

for i in tokenizer(text):
    print(i)
```

The input stored in the text file-

```
abx
*
22;
print "example" 
time = 26
```

When I hard code the input into the tokenizer, it works- the program outputs the correct tokens. Like this-

```
#for i in tokenizer("abx * 22; print \"example\"  time = 26"):
  #print(i)
```

However, I'm required to open the text file, grab the input from the file, then analyze it, but that won't work. This is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/XX/PycharmProjects/check/lexical.py", line 35, in <module>
    for i in tokenizer(text):

File "C:/Users/XX/PycharmProjects/check/lexical.py", line 26, in tokenizer
    raise Exception('Cannot output tokens') 
Exception: Cannot output tokens
```

Comment: Can you show the full code? I.e. which package are you importing the tokenizer from?

Also, you call your file "x", and then close an object "f". You also have unnecessary semicolons at the end of some lines in your code.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. I'll edit in the rest of the code...I didn't import tokenizer from any package, all I imported was "re" for regex.

Comment: Please don't remove the question like that. Others may search for the same problem and benefit from the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the reputation to comment, so I am posting as an answer.
Iterating over your file (`for line in iter(x)`) is better done as `for line in x.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, a shorter version of your code. Always prefer "with" syntax over explicit `open` and `close`.

```
with open("Tokens.txt") as f:
    text = " ".join(f.readlines())

[print(i) for i in tokenizer(text)]
```